# Rerun rule if Rust project was updated

Tags: rust, snakemake

I have a Snakemake workflow with a rule that executes some Rust code.

I understand that to rerun that rule whenever the Rust code is updated, I have to specify all Rust sources as input. My directory layout is the following:

```
Snakefile
|- implementation // subfolder containing a Rust workspace.
   |- Cargo.toml
   |- crateA
      |- Cargo.toml
      |- src // directory tree containing *.rs files
   |- crateB
      |- Cargo.toml
      |- src // directory tree containing *.rs files
   |- crateC
      |- Cargo.toml
      |- src // directory tree containing *.rs files
```

I would like to rerun the rule when any source file or Cargo.toml in the workspace is changed.
Is there some standard way to do that?

And if not, how do I list all Rust **source files** and **Cargo.toml**s as input of a Snakemake rule automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can collect all source files and toml files in a list and pass that list to the rule(s) that need it. E.g.

```
import pathlib

toml_input = pathlib.Path('implementation').glob('**/*.toml')

rule one:
    input:
        toml_input,
    ...
```

How you want to collect those files is up to you of course...